# OpenWRT USB attached disk spin-down

Tags: usb, electrical-power, openwrt

I use a couple of [ASUS WL-500GP](http://usa.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=8el2DcrRjLoHNdQ8) running [OpenWrt](http://www.openwrt.org/) Kamikaze 8.09.1 (2.4 kernel)
 as small office gateways and firewall. Now I would like to attach USB disks to cache local backup-data during office-hours and send it over the net during night.

The problem is that the attached disk never spins down and gets hot and noisy. 
Do anyone know of any "OK" solution to spin down idle USB attached disks in [OpenWrt](http://www.openwrt.org/)?

My disk device is: `/dev/scsi/host0/bus0/target0/lun0/disc`

I have tried hd-idle but no go, even tried to create a /dev/sda with mknod:

```
root@TheBrick:~# hd-idle -t sda -i 10 
ioctl on sda:: Invalid argument

root@TheBrick:~# hd-idle -t scsi/host0/bus0/target0/lun0/disc  -i 10   
ioctl on scsi/host0/bus0/target0/lun0/disc:: Invalid argument
```

Also tried "scsi-spin" but found nothing compiled for Kamikaze 8.09.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [sdparm](http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sdparm.html).  It looks like there is an [official OpenWRT package](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/2481), which you should be able to install via opkg/ipkg.

Try this:

```
opkg update
opkg install sdparm
sdparm -v --command=stop /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you have/can fetch an application, but hdparm works nice in Ubuntu Linux.

```
hdparm -y /dev/sdX
```

makes the drive enter "standby" mode, and

```
hdparm -Y /dev/sdX
```

enters sleep mode.
To setup spindown time to approx 30sec, set one of these:

```
hdparm -B 10 /dev/sdX
hdparm -S 4 /dev/sdX
```

Also, this can be configured in /etc/hdparm.conf:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/BACKUP-HDD {
        apm = 40
        }
```

Comment: `hdparm` is available via `opkg` on my openwrt 19.07.0.